# @"transform.rotation.y" animation loses layer opacity on an UIView subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation

I am using `CAKeyframeAnimation` for doing animations on a `UIView` subclass.

When I apply a `transform.rotation.y` (or `transform.rotation.x`), over a `UIView` subclass the object drawn loses opacity. I can't imagine why...

I test some scenarios:

- With `transform.rotation.z`, opacity is OK
- With `position`, opacity is OK
- Using a predefined `UIView` declared at .nib opacity is OK with `transform.rotation.y` and `transform.rotation.x`

Is there any special consideration for `transform.rotation.y` and `transform.rotation.x` at `-drawRect:`?

Thanks for answers

Comment: For your edification: see “loose/lose” entry on http://learnyourdamnhomophones.com/ (super useful site, though it does bend the meaning of “homophone” slightly), also check out the **Code Spans** section on http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Ok, I read it. Sorry for my poor english. :(